# Which resources are included with pydrake FindResourceOrThrow?

Tags: drake

In pydrake, the following line successfully locates an SDF file:

```
my_sdf = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole.sdf")
```

Given the structure of the github repository and [this example](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/multibody/four_bar/passive_simulation.cc), I would expect the following line to work as well,

```
my_sdf = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/multibody/four_bar/four_bar.sdf")
```

but it fails with `RuntimeError: Could not find Drake resource_path...`.

Why is this? Are only some of the SDF files included with the python bindings? If so, is there a list of such available files anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are only some of the SDF files included with the python bindings?

Yes, that's correct.

> If so, is there a list of such available files anywhere?

If you installed using https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html, then you can list the installed SDFormat files for your current version of the Drake wheel like so:

```
$ find env/lib/python*/site-packages/pydrake/share/drake -name '*.sdf'
...
env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/share/drake/examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole.sdf
...
```

If you installed via some other mechanism, the command would be similar but you'd need to change the `find` path to wherever Drake is installed.

> Why is this?

Drake is primary a library of [stable code](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/), not a [library of models](https://drake.mit.edu/model_version_control.html).  We generally expect users to create their own models, possibly by copying and modifying some example models to get started.

Some model files are very large (e.g., meshes or textures).  If we included those in our wheels, the wheel would exceed the default size allowed by PyPI.

We currently do install some models along with our wheels to facilitate our tutorials, but we plan to [stop installing those](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16780) and instead [download them at runtime](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/9498) for the tutorials.

The set of installed models for a given version of Drake is somewhat random, and will generally shrink from one release to the next.  If you need a [stable version](https://drake.mit.edu/stable.html#model-files) of Drake model(s), you should copy the model file(s) into your own project directly.